# R: cowplot plot_grid centering single figure on one row

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, plot-grid

With three individual plots `plot1`, `plot2` and `plot3`, the command `plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol = 2)` creates a 2 x 2 plot area, in which the top row consists of two plots and the bottom row of a single plot aligned to the left. Hence, the bottom right corner of the plot area is empty.

How can I center the individual `plot3` on the bottom row so that the 2 x 2 does not appear to be missing a fourth plot? Also, I would need `plot3` to have the same size as the other two plots.

**Reproducible example**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 2) # creates 2 x 2 plot area with missing empty bottom right corner (instead of p3 centered on bottom row)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With nested cowplots:

```r
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
plot_grid(
  plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 1, ncol = 2),
  plot_grid(NULL, p3, NULL, nrow = 1, rel_widths = c(0.5, 1, 0.5)),
  nrow = 2
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to switch to `patchwork` which via the `design` argument of `wrap_plots` or `plot_layout` gives a lot of control to place the plots in a grid:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

design <- "
AABB
#CC#
"

list(p1, p2, p3) |> 
  wrap_plots(design = design)
```

[image]